# Which of these queries are faster, when used with SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check whether a table contains a row or not. Which is faster?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE)
```

or

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: You can test this yourself

Comment: The execution plans should be equivalent.

Comment: Please have a look at the execution plan.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1061848-391-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the queries!

The columns in the select don't get evaluated. 
If you recall Logical Query processing, the from clause is executed first. The select clause is executed in the last step (actually Order By is, but that is a cosmetic thing).

So when the from clause gets executed, there are rows returned, regardless of the column names.
You have to add columnnames because otherwise you get syntax errors

Answer (score -1):

Obviously SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE is faster.

since the index scan is reduced to one,number of rows return is one and
the estimated operation cost is also much less.

but if there is only on row in the table both the queries will show same operation cost.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT top 1 * 
      FROM ms_data)  temp  
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM ms_data
```

both the above queries have same operation cost.

Comment: **Not really** - that's a **myth**. There is **NO DIFFERENCE** between `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Table)` and `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table)`. The `IF EXISTS` **only** checks for existance - it doesn't actually **return any data** so it's totally irrelevant whether you use `SELECT *` or `SELECT 1` .....

Comment: Did you look at the execution plan? In any case (more than 1 row, no row) They do have same execution plan+ IO statistics

Answer (score -1):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE)
```

is faster

there are some more suggestions

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT null FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: Not really - that's **a myth** - there is **NO DIFFERENCE** between `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Table)` and `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Table)`. The `IF EXISTS` **only** checks for existance - it doesn't actually **return any data** so it's totally irrelevant whether you use `SELECT *` or `SELECT 1` .....

Comment: @HbV2, Can you explain the reason behind saying this query is faster? In any case the queries has same execution plan, IO statistics also is similar...

Comment: That's interesting, marc_s.  I've been using T-SQL since V7 and I've always been told/heard that SELECT 1 is better than SELECT * when doing an exists as well.  It actually makes sense what you're saying, I just thought the engine had to populate the fields first before executing the check which is why * would be slower than 1.

Comment: [optimization-tips](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/16/sql-server-stored-procedure-optimization-tips-best-practices/)
please check..

Comment: @Stuart: it's a very common mistake to think that. But really: there is **no** difference between the two! Point is: no data is being returned - no columns need to be found or anything - SQL Server just really checks whether there's at least one row that matches the `WHERE` criteria - and if there is, it stops right there (other than the `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` which continues to the end of the table - even if you want to just find out whether one row exists or not)